# Switching between multiple applications in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making personal assistant app .The main app has multiple apps like notepad,calculator,calendar,reminder. This apps have own python and kivy files.I want to call this sections like start another activity in android. I could not do it using ScreenManger. Any ideas on how to do this? cause i'm not sure where to start.

Comment: why isn't it possible in screenmanager?

Comment: You can use [Pyjnius](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-for-android) on Android. However, the normal and cross-platform way would be to use ScreenManger.

Comment: so how can i call python file in screenmanager kv? i'm just a beginner with kivy.

Comment: You don't need to "call python files in screenmanager", you can make your apps as seperate screens and put all those screens in your screenmanager.